# Hazelcast - IMap how to use quorum for lock operations?

Tags: java, locking, hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

I want to use Quorum for map lock operations for my map : myMap.

I use programmatic configuration for quorum.

```
        QuorumConfig quorumConfig = new QuorumConfig();
        quorumConfig.setName("xxx");
        quorumConfig.setEnabled(true);

        quorumConfig.setQuorumFunctionImplementation(new QuorumFunction() {
            @Override
            public boolean apply(Collection<Member> members) {
                ...
            }
        });
```

I  use com.hazelcast.config.MapConfig.setQuorumName method to set quorum ımpl.

My map config seems below as quorum is set to xxx.

MapConfig{name='myMap', inMemoryFormat=BINARY', ...., mapAttributeConfigs=null, quorumName=xxx, queryCacheConfigs=null, cacheDeserializedValues=INDEX_ONLY}

The problem is, for lock operations, quorum function is not invoked.

For map put /remove operations I see that quorum function is respected.

`com.hazelcast.quorum.QuorumException: Cluster quorum failed
    at com.hazelcast.quorum.impl.QuorumImpl.newQuorumException(QuorumImpl.java:164)
    at com.hazelcast.quorum.impl.QuorumImpl.ensureQuorumPresent(QuorumImpl.java:158)
    at com.hazelcast.quorum.impl.QuorumServiceImpl.ensureQuorumPresent(QuorumServiceImpl.java:127)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.OperationRunnerImpl.ensureQuorumPresent(OperationRunnerImpl.java:237)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.OperationRunnerImpl.run(OperationRunnerImpl.java:178)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationexecutor.impl.OperationThread.process(OperationThread.java:120)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationexecutor.impl.OperationThread.run(OperationThread.java:100)
    at ------ submitted from ------.(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.getStackTrace(Thread.java:1117)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.InvocationFuture.resolve(InvocationFuture.java:114)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.InvocationFuture.resolveAndThrowIfException(InvocationFuture.java:75)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.AbstractInvocationFuture.get(AbstractInvocationFuture.java:155)
    at com.hazelcast.map.impl.proxy.MapProxySupport.invokeOperation(MapProxySupport.java:373)
    at com.hazelcast.map.impl.proxy.MapProxySupport.removeInternal(MapProxySupport.java:508)
    at com.hazelcast.map.impl.proxy.MapProxyImpl.remove(MapProxyImpl.java:211)`

**But quorum is NOT USED FOR lock operations.**

In the documentation xml config is given for lock operations.

http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/latest-development/manual/html/Distributed_Data_Structures/Map/Locking_Maps.html

> Example config is given as:
>
> An example of declarative configuration:
>
> ```
> <map name="myMap">
>   <quorum-ref>map-actions-quorum</quorum-ref>
> </map>
>
> <lock name="myMap">
>     <quorum-ref>map-lock-actions-quorum</quorum-ref>
> </lock>
> ```
>
> Here the configured map will use the map-lock-actions-quorum quorum
>   for map lock actions and the map-actions-quorum quorum for other map
>   actions.

What is the programmatic equivalent of this?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a sample for configuring Quorum for Lock:

```
Config config = new Config();
LockConfig lockConfig = new LockConfig();
lockConfig.setName("myLock")
          .setQuorumName("quorum-name");
config.addLockConfig(lockConfig);
```

Check out link for details: http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.8.3/manual/html-single/index.html#lock-configuration

Comment: So I should set the name of the lockConfig as the name of my map? In my case lockConfig.setName("myMap") ?

Comment: You need to set the Quorum name appropriately. See NOTE from documentation: "As mentioned above, a quorum definition for a lock that has the same name or a pattern that matches a map name will force the map locking actions to use the defined quorum. It is important to keep this in mind when using lock quorum and map locking actions."